# Retrieving multiple matched tokens from a regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

Here's what I want to happen

```
> /x(y\d)*/.somefunction('xy1y2y3').each { |x| puts x }
y1
y2
y3
```

This seems like a pretty natural use of the asterisk in a regexp.  I've matched a bunch of tokens and I want them printed out.

The closest I've been able to find is:

```
/x((y\d)*)/.match('xy1y2y3')[1].scan(/y\d/).each { |x| puts x }
```

Which is just abysmal.

Comment: What do you want it to look like instead if your output is abysmal?

Comment: @theTinMan -- the output is fine.  It's the code that's abysmal.  I have to manually break the regexp up into two stages to accomplish a single task.  It's one step up from using `.split`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into has to do with the regex rather than Ruby.  [You are repeating a capture group rather than capturing a repeated group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).  You could use

```
str.scan(/x((?:y\d)*)/)
```

However, this will capture all of the groups combined as one string.  In order to do what you actually want to do (check that the string follows the pattern `x` followed by these groups) you unfortunately need to do two steps as you are doing in your question.  Either that, or you can remove the additional requirement and search only for the pattern as other answers are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want:

```
'xy1y2y3'.gsub(/y\d/) { |s| puts s }
```

The `gsub` method accepts a block.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input and output, this looks about right:

```
'xy1y2y3'.scan(/y\d/)
# => ["y1", "y2", "y3"]
```

Use this if you want to print them:

```
puts 'xy1y2y3'.scan(/y\d/)
# >> y1
# >> y2
# >> y3
```

String's [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-scan) is your friend if you want to look through a string and capture repeating patterns.

Comment: But does the wrong thing with `'zy1y2y3'`!  (It should print out nothing.) The rest of the regexp is important.

Comment: Why should it print nothing? And where does your question say that? You need to define your inputs and acceptable outputs a LOT better.